# How to create a SoftwareBitmap from region of another SoftwareBitmap (UWP)

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-iot-core

What is the most efficient (easiest) way to create a new `Windows.Graphics.Imaging.SoftwareBitmap` object with a copy of region (`BitmapBounds` for example) of another `SoftwareBitmap` object (deep copy), for Windows UWP application?

There is no such constructor or static method for `SoftwareBitmap`. All Copy* methods copies whole bitmap.

I played with `WriteableBitmap` to achieve this:

```
    SoftwareBitmap CreateFromBitmap(SoftwareBitmap bmp, Rect rect)
    {
        WriteableBitmap wbmpIn = new WriteableBitmap(bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight);
        bmp.CopyToBuffer(wbmpIn.PixelBuffer);

        WriteableBitmap wbmpOut = new WriteableBitmap((int)rect.Width, (int)rect.Height);
        wbmpOut.Blit(new Rect(0, 0, rect.Width, rect.Height), wbmpIn, rect);

        SoftwareBitmap ret = new SoftwareBitmap(bmp.BitmapPixelFormat, (int)rect.Width, (int)rect.Height);
        ret.CopyFromBuffer(wbmpOut.PixelBuffer);

        return ret;
    }
```

But it doesn't look effective - involves two CopyFromBuffer() and one Blit().

Is there a more efficient solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to following code, it can create a new cropped SoftwareBitmap from an existing SoftwareBitmap.

```
    private async Task<SoftwareBitmap> CreateFromBitmap(SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap, Rect rect)
    {
        using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.BmpEncoderId, stream);

            encoder.SetSoftwareBitmap(softwareBitmap);

            encoder.BitmapTransform.Bounds = new BitmapBounds()
            {
                X = (uint)rect.X,
                Y = (uint)rect.Y,
                Height = (uint)rect.Height,
                Width = (uint)rect.Width
            };

            await encoder.FlushAsync();

            BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);

            return await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync(softwareBitmap.BitmapPixelFormat, softwareBitmap.BitmapAlphaMode);
        }
    }



    var croppedBitmap = await CreateFromBitmap(sourceSoftwareBmp, new Rect(0, 0, 200, 100));
```

[image]